# JS Text to image changing the size of font

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/WxmQR/1

HTML:

```
<canvas id='textCanvas' height=20></canvas>
<img id='image'>
<br>
<textarea id='text'></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
canvas{
    border: 1px black solid;
}
#textCanvas{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
    imageElem = document.getElementById('image');

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function (){
    tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
    tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
    imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(imageElem.src);
}, false);
```

This Code is what I want but I want to be able to make the font size bigger, have a fixed width and height for the image and make the text to over flow to the next line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh you mean the things you write within the textarea?

Comment: I mean the out put. I want the out put of the text to be larger

Comment: Use `.css()`. Insert JQuery within your code.

Comment: which class do i target to edit the size of the font ?

Comment: Within whichever class your font is in.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way:

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
```

How ever, this will add the `style` attribute to the text area element, which is not recommended. instead, create a class with the desired font size and call it like this:

```
document.getElementById("myP").className = "MyClass";
```

As the best practice states, all designs should be inside a style sheet (css file) and not defined in the html element itself.

Comment: where do I put the mP ?

Comment: This is merely an example. In your case, 'myP' is 'text' which means, the ID of the html element and "MyClass" is the class you create in which you define the font-size and add it to the text area element via 'ClassName' Attribute.